# Hang-fire server becomes zero

Tags: .net-core, hangfire

While creating a JOB in the **hang-fire** server's become enabled and we can see the count of the number of servers are more than one but after some time server count becomes zero and due to that job isn't running (**I mean the jobs are not triggering**), is there any known solution for this issue.

> Server Count becomes **(0)**

[image]

Clearing up the hand-fire DB and restarting is one way but that is not a permanent fix is there a proper fix for this issue?

Comment: I also encountered this issue sometimes, did't find the root cause, I just cleaned up the hangfire job db and restarted.

Comment: this should help https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html#making-asp-net-application-always-running and especially this part https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html#making-asp-net-core-application-always-running-on-iis